# Table like layout in responsive design cross browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

In a webpage i have following markup for my layout

```
<div class="parent">
      <div class="left-content"></div>
      <div class="right-content"></div>
</div>
```

and the styles for the given markup are:

```
.parent{
   display:table;
   width:100%;
}
.parent > .left-content{
   width:auto;
}
.parent > .right-content{
   width:320px;
}
```

How do I make the "right-content" occupy 320px of available width and the "left-content" div occupy all the remaining width?

**Note that:** i can not use the following technique to achieve this behaviour as my layout is responsive and i need to move the "right-content" to the bottom of "left-content" at specific resolution.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="right-content"></div>          
     <div class="left-content"></div>
</div>
```

**Styles**

```
.parent{
   display:block;
   width:100%;
}
.parent > .left-content{
   width:auto;
}
.parent > .right-content{
   width:320px;
   float:right;
}
```

Comment: Are you even asking a question here?

Comment: Take a look at this sentence.   "Now the problem is how the "left-content" div occupy all remaining space, where the "right-content" occupy 320px of available width."

Comment: That's not a question... That's a statement. What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: what i want is clearly described in the statement. "how the 'left-content' div occupy all remaining space, where the 'right-content'  occupy 320px of available width".

Comment: Abdul, I'm also not really getting your question. Perhaps you can make a fiddle and show us what the challenge is, and what it is you're trying to achieve. I'd like to help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things easier I would first change the markup so you have the left content is below your right-content (as desired on smartphone-resolutions).

```
 <div class="left-content"></div>
 <div class="right-content"></div>
```

Next, because your first div is the one that takes up remaining width, the simple solution seems to be `display:table-cell` (and the parent as `display:table`). It looks doable with inline-blocks or floats as well, but you may have to resort to something like `width: calc(100% - 320px);` so I like the table solution a little bit more.

Next you add a simple media query to change back to blocks on lower resolutions.

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.parent > .left-content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;        

  /* Added for visualisation */
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.parent > .right-content {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 320px;

  /* Added for visualisation */
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
    
/* Media query */
@media(max-width: 550px) {
.parent > .left-content {
  display: block;
}
.parent > .right-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-content">Left</div>
  <div class="right-content">Right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest using `calc` rather than forcing your markup to behave like a table.

http://sassmeister.com/gist/c87585fcff7fae356adb

```
.left-content,
.right-content {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {

  .left-content {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 320px);
  }

  .right-content {
    float: right;
    width: 320px;
  }
}
```

Comment: 'calc' is not cross browser supported.

Comment: Well if you are still supporting old IE, then you could use display table as a browser specific fallback. Modern first... Degrade gracefully.